# Why does clicking links on my site not change the URL in the browser's address bar?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

I expect this is a basic question but I'm not sure what to search for in order to get the answer...

I'm hosting a site using Apache 2.2 (on Mac OS X 10.6) and I use a Directory and an Alias directive in httpd.conf to serve a set of pages outside Apache's DocumentRoot.  The URL looks like this to the user:

`http://mysite/root`

I have it set to automatically serve index.html if you don't specify a file so in fact that is serving:

`http://mysite/root/index.html`

On that index page I have links to other files in the same directory (e.g. about.html) in the filesystem.  If I click one it loads the page fine.  The thing I'm trying to figure out is why the URL in the browser's address bar *doesn't change* when I do that.  In other words the address bar doesn't look like this:

`http://mysite/root/about.html`

Why is that?  I assume this is some default that Apache uses?  Can I set it so that it does show the actual file name in the address?  At the moment it still shows:

`http://mysite/root`

which is annoying as when I refresh the page in my browser it serves me index.html again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is not an Apache issue, but like your `index.html` is using [HTML frames](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp). So, to get rid of this behavior, you'll have to get rid of the frames.

Update, as this is your DNS provider adding those frames:

If you have a fixed [public IP address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/), then any normal DNS provider allows you to map your domain to some specific IP address, instead of using some magical frameset. [Your DNS provider](http://www.names.co.uk/domains.html) seems to offer [this as well](http://www.names.co.uk/knowledge/domains/domain_configuration_and_dns/879-how_do_i_update_my_dns.html).

Comment: Interesting. I haven't added frames myself but it looks like something did! It must have been apache or my domain name/ dns lookup provider?

Comment: @Ben, if you're indeed using some domain service that forwards requests for `some-nice-domain.com` to your own computer, then sometimes/often that indeed uses a frameset for "forwarding". The outermost frameset is then served by computer registered at the nice domain name, while the inner frames then refer to some IP address or some `not-too-nice.looking.domain.com` to include the actual site content.

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I bet that's it! I'll pursue that line and see if that's the case! If it I'd I'll be accepting your answer. Either way it was a good insight so I'm voting up!

Comment: @Ben, it seems you've got accepting and voting mixed up (but: you can undo both accepting and voting) :-) Which [dynamic DNS service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dns) are you using? And what does Apache give you when accessing through `http://localhost` directly, without that third-party DNS service?

Comment: Ok so it looks like I've accepted your answer I just can't vote it up (not enough rep!). I'll check when I get back on my machine. Cheers.

Comment: I have a domain name provided by Namesco (in the UK) and it wraps every page in a frameset.  How do I remove that?  How irritating that this happens!

Comment: @Ben, it might be on option you can change, but when changing that you might not see your nice domain name any longer. If you have a fixed IP address, then you can set up DNS records to point to your own IP address right away (just the way DNS is supposed to work, without any trickery of a third-party wrapping your IP address in some HTML for you).

Comment: Yep, I contacted my provider and I can redirect but then I don't get my nice domain name.  Ho hum.  Thanks for the help Arjan - I learning something here.